# Sails.js: Could not populate model because of ambiguous usage

Tags: node.js, sails.js, sails-postgresql

I'm having two models of let's say **A** and **B**. It's an 1:n relation, where one **A** owns one **B**, and **B** can be owned my multiple **A**s.

Now, if possible, **B** shouldn't have to know about all the **A**s it's referenced in, so I'm only associating on the **A** side.

Now I want to search for all **A**s that own a **B** with a certain criteria. I've basically tried this:

```
A.find()
  .populate('B', {
    where: {
      someAttr: 1
    }
  })
```

Looking at the documentation I find this pretty similar to the example [there](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/queries/populate).

Now I'm getting the following error:

> Could not populate `B` because of ambiguous usage.  This is a
>   singular ("model") association, which means it never refers to more
>   than *one* associated record.  So passing in subcriteria (i.e. as the
>   second argument to `.populate()`) is not supported for this
>   association, since it generally wouldn't make any sense.  But that's
>   the trouble-- it looks like some sort of a subcriteria (or something)
>   *was* provided!

Can I somehow make this query work without giving **B** a reference back on **A**? I feel like this is unnecessary bloating of the models.

I'm using Sails 1.0.1 right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into the [docs](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/queries/populate) about the second argument `subcriteria` to `populate` :

> When populating collection associations between two models which reside in the same database, a Waterline criteria may be specified as a second argument to populate. This will be used for filtering, sorting, and limiting the array of associated records (e.g. snacks) associated with **EACH** primary record.

One way you can do this is to retrieve all the records then filter them, or use a native query directly.